# Unable to download a software component: com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit/1.13.0. Error while uploading the ipa from xcode

Tags: xcode, upload, app-store-connect

I've uploaded a number of builds of this app. But today I am seeing a weird error as shown below image 
[image]

It is showing as

Upload Failed: App Store Connection Operation Error.

> Unable to download a software component:
>   com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit/1.13.0

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Connect to a different network and try again. It worked for me. Probably your current network is not allowing certain files to be downloaded.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue in my case I placed the xcode on some root folder not in /Applications and had that error and a whole bunch of other similar errors,reinstalled to /Applications and that seemed to have cured my issue